# extract value from a cell that has formula in it and paste in another cell

Tags: vba, extract, formula

I tried below code to extract the value from AI31 cell in Sheet1(AI31 has formula in it) and to paste the value in C2 in Sheet3

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Evaluate(Range("AI31").Formula).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C2")
```

However it doesn't work(VBA)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is sophisticated beyond necessity.

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AL31").Value
```

As .Value is default property of Range object, you could omit it, nevertheless, I like to type it in my macros.

Comment: I have used like below to get the values from one tab to my summary sheet. Is there any better way to take AI31,AI45,AI60 values from all sheets named Jan,Feb, etc till Dec and put it in summary sheet without writing below three lines 12 time?           
 Worksheets("Summary").Activate
Worksheets("Summary").Range("C2").Value = Worksheets("Jan").Range("AI31").Value
Worksheets("Summary").Range("C3").Value = Worksheets("Jan").Range("AI45").Value
Worksheets("Summary").Range("C4").Value = Worksheets("Jan").Range("AI60").Value